# How to create a comma-separated string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios4

I want to create a comma-separated string like this.

**NSString *list = @"iPhone,iPad,iPod";**

I tried like this,

```
[strItemList appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,", [[arrItems objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"ItemList"]]];
```

But the issue is I'm getting a string like this
  **@"iPhone,iPad,iPod,"** Note that there is an extra comma "," at the end of the string. How can I avoid that extra comma?

Can you please give me a hint. Highly appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use substringToIndex option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Completion of loop add below stmt

```
strItemList = [strItemList substringToIndex:[strItemList length]-1]
```

Comment: This technically works, but the preferred idiom is componentsJoinedByString. it's more concise and potentially faster.

Comment: @Scott as per question he have array with Dictionary.as per requirement only i given answer

Answer (score 12):

To join an array of strings into a single string by a separator (character which would be a string), you could use this method of `NSArray` class:

```
NSArray* array = @[@"iPhone", @"iPad", @"iPod"];
NSString* query = [array componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

By using this method, you won't need to drop the last extra comma (or whatever) because it won't add it to the final string.

Answer (score 4):

There's a couple of routes you can take.

If the number of items is always the same, and known before hand (which I guess isn't the case, but I mention it for completeness's sake), just make the whole string at once:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@", [[arrItems objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"ItemList"]], [[arrItems objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"ItemList"]], [[arrItems objectAtIndex:2] objectForKey:@"ItemList"]]
```

Knowing that the unwanted comma will always be the last character in the string, you can make removing it the last step in construction:

```
} // End of loop
[strItemList removeCharactersInRange:(NSRange){[strItemList length] - 1, 1}];
```

Or you can change your thinking a little and do the loop like this:

```
NSString * comma = @"";
for( i = 0; i < [arrItems count]; i++ ){

    [strItemList appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", comma, [[arrItems objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"ItemList"]]];
    comma = @",";
}
```

Notice that `comma` comes *before* the other item. Setting that string inside the loop means that nothing will be added on the first item, but a comma character will be for every other item.

Answer (score 1):

check the value of array count if array count is last then add without comma else add with comma. try this out i am not sure to much about.

```
if([arrItems objectAtIndex:i] == arrItems.count){  
[strItemList appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[arrItems objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"ItemList"]]];
}

else {
[strItemList appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,", [[arrItems objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"ItemList"]]];
```

}

Comment: Thanks all of you for the support. I was able to solve it, thanks again :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `arrItems` is an `NSArray` with elements @"iPhone", @"iPad", and @"iPod", you can do this:

```
NSArray *list = [arrItems componentsJoinedByString:@","]
```

Answer (score 0):

NSArray with elements @"iPhone", @"iPad", and @"iPod"

```
NSString *str=[[arrItems objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"ItemList"]]

str =   [str stringByAppendingFormat:@",%@",[[arrItems objectAtIndex:1]objectForKey:@"ItemList"]]];
str =   [str stringByAppendingFormat:@",%@",[[arrItems objectAtIndex:2]objectForKey:@"ItemList"]]];
NsLog(@"%@",str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Assuming...
NSDictionary *dictionary1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"iPhone", @"iPodTouch", nil] forKey:@"ItemList"];
NSDictionary *dictionary2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"iPad", @"iPad2", @"Apple TV", nil] forKey:@"ItemList"];
NSDictionary *dictionary3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"iMac", @"MacBook Pro", @"Mac Pro", nil] forKey:@"ItemList"];
NSArray *arrItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dictionary1, dictionary2, dictionary3, nil];

// create string list
NSString *strItemList = [[arrItems valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.ItemList"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
NSLog(@"All Items List: %@", strItemList);
```

Output: 
All Items List: iPhone, iPodTouch, iPad, iPad2, Apple TV, iMac, MacBook Pro, Mac Pro

Answer (score 0):

This method will return you the nsmutablestring with comma separated values from an array

-(NSMutableString *)strMutableFromArray:(NSMutableArray *)arr withSeperater:(NSString *)saperator
{
    NSMutableString *strResult = [NSMutableString string];

```
for (int j=0; j<[arr count]; j++)
{
    NSString *strBar = [arr objectAtIndex:j];
    [strResult appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strBar]];
    if (j != [arr count]-1)
    {
        [strResult appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",seperator]];
    }
}
return strResult;
```

}